# Opening Windows XP on a Windows 8 machine

Tags: windows-8, windows-xp, hard-drive

I have bought a new PC that had Windows 8 pre-installed, but I need all my previous data, programmes and, especially my emails (about 50,000) on my new machine that ran with XP and Outlook Express.

I have had my hard drive on my old machine cloned on to the new hard drive. I put it back in to the new machine.

I have managed to get the new machine to access the new hard drive where my clone is. BUT. It starts booting XP then crashes to a blue screen, that flashes by, but I think shows registary errors.

Help?

Comment: Do you want to recover data or boot entire system?

Comment: WHY would you do this when you could simply slave your XP disk to your Windows 8 machine (USB-to-SATA/IDE, for example) and you'll be able to copy the Outlook Express email data files (OST/PST) to your Windows 8 machine where, I'll guess, you've got Outlook installed... all your emails will then open in Outlook in Windows 8...

Comment: You are not going to accomplish your goal without first running *SysPrep* on your old machine before you clone the drive after doing so. Personally I would just use a third-party tool to accomplish your goal that support restoring the image to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The situation is that I have the cloned disc, and its not possible for me to go backwards now. 

In answer to  gronostaj I want to boot the entire system. On the cloned hard drive I have XP installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the new machine has UEFI rather than traditional BIOS. **If** XP can run on that machine as the primary OS (it might not have drivers for your new hardware, for example), you probably need to enable legacy boot in UEFI and turn off security enhancements. If XP cannot run, then you might have to get Windows 8 installation media for your machine.

As Big Chris noted, you would have been better off accessing your old programs and data from Windows 8 (I have found all my legacy XP programs work well on Windows 8), or, if you *must* have the XP interface, Use Classic Shell or run a virtual machine under Windows 8 with XP.